# Running Parallel Jobs and getting the aggregated results

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I had a quick question about the workflow plugin. I'm trying to see if the plugin will be able to satisfy my use case:

- We have a jenkins job that will build our app
- We want to spin off a suite of test jobs that will perform various tests on the newly built app (unit, integration, etc). These will need to be run in parallel and we want to run them on more than one jenkins node for performance reasons
- We'll take the aggregated output from all our test processes from step 2 and be able to decide whether or not we should deploy (everything's passed) or not

I was curious as to whether or not I'd be able to accomplish this within the plugin and if so if you had any tips/pointers to a start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly run `node`s inside `parallel` branches. If one branch fails, the `parallel` step as a whole fails. If you want the build to succeed, but behave differently depending on test results, you can capture them directly as Groovy variables in various ways.

If you are using `JUnitArchiver`, currently it does not provide a simple means of exposing the test results directly to the Pipeline script ([JENKINS-26276](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26276)), though if you just want to tell if there are some failures or none, you can inspect `currentBuild.status`.

If you have JUnit-format test results and wish to *automatically* split them amongst various nodes (especially helpful in case you have a large pool of machines and it would be unmaintainable to manually divide your tests), see [this demo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parallel-test-executor-plugin/blob/master/demo/README.md) of the Parallel Test Executor plugin’s `splitTests` step.